# Animate removal of UITableViewCellAccessory

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-animation

Is there any way to animate the removal of a UITableView cell accessory?

I currently am showing a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator, but I would like to animate swapping the disclosure indicator with a UISwitch on all visible table cells.

I've tried something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                   for (SwitchTableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells)
                   {
                     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                   }                     
                 }];
```

... but unfortunately that has no affect. The disclosure indicator abruptly disappears and the contentView width jumps in one step, rather than a smooth transition.

Answer (score 3):

accessoryType is not an animatable property. There are two ways you can do this, depending on your situation. The easiest only applies if you are changing the accessory to a UISwitch because of entering the editing state. In this case, just use`cell.editingAccessoryType = theSwitch;` in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The table view will then do a fade in/out automatically when entering editing mode.

If you are doing this outside of editing mode, then the following code will do what you want:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    for(SwitchTableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        [[cell valueForKey:@"_accessoryView"] setAlpha:0.0];
    }
} completion:^(BOOL done) {
    for(SwitchTableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        cell.accessoryView = theSwitch;
    }
}];
```

However, I do not know if this code will make it into the app store since it uses the hidden property _accessoryView.